# Rendering exported 3D objects on Android using min3D

Tags: android, model, blender

I'm creating a bike racing game for Android. I am planning to create models in Blender, export them to .obj format and then render them on the device. I'm using the min3D framework to do the obj parsing and rendering. I followed the tutorial in [this page](http://www.rozengain.com/blog/2010/05/17/loading-3d-models-with-the-min3d-framework-for-android/) for parsing the obj file and to render it on the screen. When I tried simple object like a cube, everything works fine and it is rendered perfectly on the screen. But when I tried to load a simple bike model I downloaded from the web, it doesn't work. The app crashes and I force stop it. When I saw LogCat, it was either a java.lang.NumberFormatException, or java.lang.NullPointerException or a resource not found exception inside the parse() method. I have no clue why this happens.

I have the following doubts about where it possibly could have gone wrong:

1) According to the given tutorial, I changed the file names from .obj and .mtl to _obj and _mtl. But there was a line in the obj file that has the name of the .mtl file. I changed it to _mtl. Still it dint work. Is there something similar I need to do anywhere else? Do I need to modify any of the files in any way?

2) Sometimes I find that models created in Blender 2.49 are parsed and rendered but the models created in Blender 2.6 are causing this trouble. Also min3D was created during the older versions of Blender. So should I use only Blender 2.49 for creating the models and rendering them?

P.S: I'm completely new to graphics so I'm fighting a lot with this without giving up. Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because of missing Texture. Did you copy the texture image into res/drawable folder?